# Meaning of vector derivative of velocity with respect to position

Tags: matrix-calculus

I would like to compute an expression for $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$, where $x$ is a position vector and $v = \dot{x}$ is a velocity vector. Using the Chain Rule, we should have:

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial t}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial t}{\partial x}\dot{v}^\intercal$$

Using differentials $dx$ and $dt$, we have

$$dx = (\frac{\partial x}{\partial t})^\intercal dt, dt = (\frac{\partial t}{\partial x})^\intercal dx$$

and by combining we get

$$I = \frac{\partial t}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}$$

with some manipulation, we can get

$$v = \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}^\intercal = \frac{\partial t}{\partial x} ||v||^2$$

Thus we get

$$\frac{\partial t}{\partial x} = \frac{v}{||v||^2}$$

and finally

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \frac{v\dot{v}^\intercal}{||v||^2}$$

This seems to make logical sense from the fundamentals of matrix calculus (which I am still trying to grasp), but I am not sure how to interpret this result.

Comment: The final equation is not dimensionally consistent. The LHS has units of reciprocal time (e.g. $s^{-1}$), while the RHS is dimensionless.

Comment: Whoops, misread.

Comment: Fixed the derivation. I replaced $x$ with $v$ mistakenly after the first equality. The units should be consistent now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(x,v,a)$ denote the position, velocity, and acceleration vectors.

The Moore-Penrose inverse of the velocity vector is
$$\eqalign{
 v^+ &= \Bigg(\frac{v^T}{v^Tv}\Bigg) ^\implies v^+v=1\cr
}$$
but please note that $\,\,vv^+\ne I$

The MP inverse allows you to write
$$\eqalign{
a &= a\,(v^+v) \cr
 \frac{dv}{dt} &= av^+\,\frac{dx}{dt} \cr
}$$
Multiplying the LHS and RHS by $dt$ yields the differential result
$$\eqalign{
 dv &= av^+\,dx \cr
}$$
It is the interpretation of your next step
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} &= av^+ = {\dot v}v^+ \cr
}$$
that raises questions, since it implies that velocity (aka momentum) is a function of position. 

But position and momentum are treated as independent variables in mechanics.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer! It makes a little more sense thinking about it in terms of Moore-Penrose inverses.

Regarding the independence between position and momentum, they are still generally independent despite their codependence on time?